# BIM360 receiving js error on 3-legged OAuth

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

We have a Windows Forms application that is using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control to display BIM 360's authorization page and receive the following js error
[image]

Comment: I surpressed the display by adding ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true to the form initialization. But it doesn't address what might be an underlying issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` is rendering the page with the good old Internet Explorer and has compatibility issue running the scripts from the authorization page. Personally I wouldn't hold my breath for our team to extend their backward compatibility that far back...

Try [WebViewControl](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/05/09/modern-webview-winforms-wpf-apps/) which brings Edge to your app and that should get you support for scripts with modern syntax and features

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but we have customers that might still be running really old versions of Windows so Edge isn't an option. We are able to authenticate when suppressing display of the error messages. Can you foresee a case where doing this would result in the user not being able to authenticate?

Comment: Not that I know of - but if push comes to shove try migrate to [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/)